# Find all words that include four consecutive vowels

Tags: python, regex

Tetravocalic: Find all words that include four consecutive vowels.

```
def Tetravocalic(i):
    return(re.search("/\b.*[aeiou]+.*[aeiou]+.*[aeiou]+.*[aeiou]+{4}/\b",i)))

Tetravocalic("vajjekiohkkugh")
```

error: multiple repeat at position 42

Please let me know the meaning of the error and the correct code as well.

ex: Tetravocalic("vajjekiohkkugh apple ororaeeg")

Comment: You have 2 quantifiers `+{4}`. Your current pattern matches more than single words that include four consecutive vowels. Can you add some examples that you want to match?

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is way too complex, you only need this :`'[aeiou]{4}'`.

Example code:

```
def has_four_consecutive_vowels(s):
    return bool(re.search('[aeiou]{4}', s))
```

Comment: Thanks, sphere. It is working fine for ("vaeiough").what changes I have to do if I want to get this word also?("vajjekiohkkugh")? "^.*[aeiou]+" ---is it right? It is different from my initial question, though. should I ask it on a separate thread? –

Comment: `vajjekiohkkugh` does not include four consecutive vowels so it does not match.
What are the new rules under which `vajjekiohkkugh` should match?

Comment: new rule-- 4 vowels either consecutive or one after the other